# jquery set click on selected place of the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I have a pretty interesting task – I have an external player with volume bar and I need to imitate click on selected place of this volume bar.

If I click on the beginning of this volume bar – it will be low volume.
If I click on the end of this volume bar – it will be high volume.

I know that I can fire a trigger of all element (the whole volume bar in my case `$(".volume_bar").trigger("click");` ) but how can I fire a click trigger on the certain part of the element? For example - something like this `$(".volume_bar").trigger("click": {left:30%});`

Any ideas?

Comment: what I suggest is that you don't trigger a simulated click on the element - but fire a function call based on what that click would actually do. So for example if a user clicks the volume bar at 30% - presumably that fires  a function to change the volume to that amount. Therefore - rather than trying to trigger the fake click. Set a function call that would be the result of an actual click - perhaps with the desired amount set as an argument . eg setVolume('30%');

Comment: Which player are you using? Usually players get you an api to call functions (like youtube api etc.)

Comment: @MoshFeu, Unfortunately, this player doesn't have API :(

Comment: @gavgrif , I don't know how the player code works – the code has too many functions and dependences. The simplest way for me is to simulate click :(

Comment: Can you share with us which player are you using?

Comment: It's Netflix web player :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the element's position and then trigger a click at the desired position. You can use jQuery's [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for that and you can set the event's pageX and pageY params as defined [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

To trigger an event at a given location, the code should look like this:

```
var $element = $('#element')
$element.width() // get the width
$element.height() // get the height

var event = new $.Event('click');
event.pageX = $element.offset().left + $element.width() * 0.5
event.pageY = $element.offset().top + $element.height() * 0.5

$element.trigger(event) // this should click in the middle
```

**Warning** not tested!!! Anyway, you get the gist...